# NameError: name 'end' is not defined

Tags: python, list

```
lst=[1,2,3,'b',4,5,6,'c','b',4,5,6,2,'c',9,0,1]

def delElement(E1,E2):
    global end
    for i,ele in enumerate(lst):
        if ele==E1:
            start=i
            break
        elif ele== E2:
            end=i
            break
    del lst[start:end+1]
    return(lst)
delElement('b','c')
```

Comment: You didn't define end?

Comment: `end` wont be defined as long as your `elif` is executed

Comment: If you don't hit that line in an elif block, end is never assigned. When you hit an `E1`, you break out of your loop, so you never hit an `E2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your current code, at the moment your for loop detects E1, it breaks and go right away to del `lst[start:end+1]` without defining end. No sure what you want to achieve but keeping the same structure of code, just remove the first break:

```
def delElement(e1, e2):
        for i, ele in enumerate(lst):
            if ele == e1:
                start = i
            elif ele == e2:
                end = i
                break
        del lst[start:end + 1]
        return lst  

lst = [1, 2, 3, 'b', 4, 5, 6, 'c', 'b', 4, 5, 6, 2, 'c', 9, 0, 1]   
delElement('b', 'c')
```

I can see many potential error on the results depending of what you want to achieve exactly. Don't hesitate to add details for better answer...

**EDIT:** An ugly way but workable if your expected result is `[1, 2, 3, 9, 0, 1]`:

```
def delElement(elementA, elementB, lst):

    new_lst = []
    feed_new_lst = True  # New list is fed when this is true

    for element in lst:

        if element == elementA:
            feed_new_lst = False  # Stop feeding the new list
            continue

        if feed_new_lst:
            new_lst.append(element)

        if element == elementB:
            feed_new_lst = True  # Continue do feed the new list

    return new_lst

lst = [1, 2, 3, 'b', 4, 5, 6, 'c', 'b', 4, 5, 6, 2, 'c', 9, 0, 1]
lst2 = ['b', 2, 3, 'c', 4, 'b', 6, 'c', 4, 5, 6, 'b', 9, 0, 'c']

print(delElement('b', 'c', lst))
# [1, 2, 3, 9, 0, 1]

print(delElement('b', 'c', lst2))
# [4, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: wanted to delete list elements from 'b' to 'c'

Comment: so your expected result (based on your list) would be `[1, 2, 3, 9, 0, 1]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Even though you have defined that you want to use the global variable `end` on line 4, this variable does not have any value yet.

Since your for loop breaks after finding the value `b` in your list, the value end will never be set. Instead, only the value of the variable `start` will be set, since the first if-statement will evaluate to True first.

After the loop you are trying to delete a range of list items by referencing the variable `end`, however, since this has not been given a value yet, it will throw an error.

A solution could be to also set the `end` variable in the first if-statement, depending on your needs. Also, if possible, I would suggest avoiding using global variables like this, as explained in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil).